# jQuery - take the value of a single input with class when I click

Tags: jquery

This is my situation

```
<div id='cont-qty'></div>
<a href="#" class="bottontest">aaa<input class="inp" value="1" /></a>
<a href="#" class="bottontest">bbb<input class="inp" value="2" /></a>
<a href="#" class="bottontest">ccc<input class="inp" value="3" /></a>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("a").click(function(){
    $j("#cont-qty").html($j('.inp').val());
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click on the first  tag or on the second one I would like to take the value of each respective input. For example if I click on the second  I want me to take the value of the second input and so on.

At the moment if I click on the second or third  it always takes me only the value of the first input.

How can I do?

Comment: Your code is illegal. Use `<label for="input1"><input id="input1" class="inp" value="1" /></label>` You can use `$j("label").on("click",function() { $j("#cont-qty").html($j("#"+$j(this).attr("for")).val())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the context of your `$('.inp')` selector to `this`, which represents the `a` clicked.

You can do that by using : `$('.inp',this)`

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $("#cont-qty").html($('.inp',this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cont-qty'></div>

<a href="#" class="bottontest">aaa<input class="inp" value="1" /></a>
<a href="#" class="bottontest">bbb<input class="inp" value="2" /></a>
<a href="#" class="bottontest">ccc<input class="inp" value="3" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use context of clicked anchor(`this`) to find input element in it:

```
$j("a").click(function(){
   $j("#cont-qty").html($j(this).find('.inp').val());
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the 'this' keyword. I try to avoid it as much as posible when I write Javascript

```
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

            $j(function(){
                     $j("a").on("click",function(element){
                     $j("#cont-qty").html($j(element.target).find(".inp").val());
                    return false;
                });                             
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid. Instead use label and IDs

```
<label for="input1" class="bottontest">Aaaa<input id="input1" class="inp" value="1" /></label>
```

You can then use

```
$j("label.bottontest").on("click",function() { 
  $j("#cont-qty").html(
    $j("#"+$j(this).attr("for")).val()
  );
});
```